# php preg_match validate string if alpha or have space

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i need to validate a string that can only have letters(lowercase or uppercase) and may have space (may not have too) and a dash.

```
if(preg_match('/^[-a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $myString)) {
    //valid string
}
```

Comment: Could it be only spaces?

Comment: it should accept with or without spaces.

Comment: So `"    "` is valid?

Comment: probably not. it should have at least a single letter

Comment: And only dash `"--"` ?

Comment: the dashes and the spaces should be of optional but it should not be valid without any content of a letter. Also the input must begin with any letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this for a string contains only letter, space and dash, but at least one letter.

```
if(preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z -]+$/i', $myString)) {
  echo 'valid';
}
```

Edit:
If the input must begin with any letter, then the regex could be simplified to:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-z][a-z -]*$/i', $myString)) {
  echo 'valid';
}
```

Comment: Does it meet `Also the input must begin with any letter` requirement?

Comment: @anubhava Oh... didn't see that. With that requirement, your answer is just ok for that.

Comment: Yes it will allow `"-a"` and `"- x"` strings also. But I guess this question wasn't well defined from start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/

if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/', $myString)) {
    //valid string
}
```

**EDIT** If input must start with a letter then use:

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z -]*$/
```

Comment: Yes it will. Whatever is inside character class it will allow those characters but you can just without any of those symbols as well. So `abc` or `abc-xyz` will be allowed.